When conditioning a Gaussian process, why is the conditional mean always trending upwards?
I have a Gaussian vector with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, both estimated. The vector $\mu$ represents a process and for each entry starting with the second, I want to find the conditional distribution where the conditioning set gets bigger as we walk through the vector.
Borrowing from the theory of Gaussian processes, my idea is to write the mean vector as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_{1} & \\
\mu_{2} & \\
\vdots& \\
\mu_{i} & \\
\vdots & \\
\mu_{p}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the variance matrix $\Sigma$ as
$$
\Sigma = \left[ \begin{matrix}\Sigma_{11} & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \Sigma_{1,p}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \vdots\\
\Sigma_{i,1} & \dots & \Sigma_{i,\left(i-1\right)} & \Sigma_{i,i} & \dots & \Sigma_{1,p}\\
\vdots\\
\Sigma_{p,1} & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \Sigma_{pp}
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
so that the conditional (running) mean is
$$
\mu_{i|\left(1:i-1\right)}=\mu_{i}+\Sigma_{i,1:\left(i-1\right)}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),1:\left(i-1\right)}^{-1}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),i}
$$
and the conditional variance
$$\sigma_{i|\left(1:i-1\right)}=\Sigma_{ii}-\Sigma_{i,1:\left(i-1\right)}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),1:\left(i-1\right)}^{-1}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),i}
$$
According to the properties of the normal distribution, this vector should then just be the conditional means where each entry is conditioned on all of the previous entries.
However, when I run this on simulated data, I always get an upward-trending process, like in the picture, no matter the true underlying trend vector.
My hope is to construct a non-parametric conditional mean using the information contained in the history of the process but somehow I feel, I am doing something wrong so that I always get an upward-trending process.
The conditional mean process is $\mu_i$ with error bands $\pm 1.64  \sigma_{i|\left(1:i-1\right)}$, while the marginal has equivalent error bands.

For reference, the normal variates that I simulated have a  falling mean from $100$ down to $1$ while the covariance matrix follows a Wishart distribution with $500$ degrees of freedom and identity scale matrix.
Somehow, I am getting something wrong I think and would be grateful for an explanation why the conditional process seems to always trend up.
edit please forgive the strange typesetting of the covariance matrix and mean vector. It's rendering fine now.

On the face of it this behavior is no surprise at all, because you describe a random walk with a non-negative drift.

Thank you @whuber may I ask how exactly? I had a feeling I was but don't exactly see how.

Because $\Sigma_{i,1:\left(i-1\right)}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),1:\left(i-1\right)}^{-1}\Sigma_{1:\left(i-1\right),i}$ is non-negative, you are systematically incrementing the mean by a non-negative amount.

is the conditional (running) mean formula what you want? because that is not the mean of $X_{i} | X_{1:(i-1)}$. $E( X_{i} | X_{1:(i-1)} = x_{1:(i-1)} ) = \mu_i + \Sigma_{i, 1:(i-1)} \Sigma_{1:(i-1), 1:(i-1)}^{-1} (x_{1:(i-1)} - \mu_{1:(i-1)} )$. the drift will then depend on $\mu$, as it should
